# [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.confirm.confirm')]

Tags: react-native

I am trying to register by phone but I am getting an error [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.confirm.confirm')]. What is the reason of this?

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

class PhoneVerificationPart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            confirm: null,
            code: null
        };
    } 
signInWithPhoneNumber = async (+90....) => {

        const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        this.setState({
            confirm: confirmation
        })
    }
    confirmCode = async () => {
        try {
            await this.state.confirm.confirm(this.state.code)
            await this.props.closeAndCreateCustomer()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `this.state.confirm` from the state while it's defined as null initially and before it's reset.

Use this way

```
var phoneNumber = "+16505554567"; // should be in string

firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
      // confirmationResult can resolve with the fictional testVerificationCode above.
      return confirmationResult.confirm(testVerificationCode)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    });
```

Comment: first of all I get this error : [Error: [auth/cancelled-popup-request] User interaction is still ongoing, another view cannot be presented.]

Comment: i have @react-native-firebase/auth library